# Python - No module named '_gdal_array' only on virtual env

Tags: python, gdal

I'm trying to import `gdal_array` in python but I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_gdal_array'`.

The strange thing is that this problem does not occur if I use system's python 3.8. It only occurs inside python3.8 virtual environment

Code that works (on terminal):

```
python3.8
from osgeo import gdal_array
```

Code I used to test it in venv and doesn't work (on terminal):

```
virtualenv venv -p $(which python3.8)
source venv/bin/activate
pip install numpy 
pip install osgeo 
pip install gdal==$(gdal-config --version)
python3.8
from osgeo import gdal_array
```

Above code results in:

```
>>> from osgeo import gdal_array
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/osgeo/gdal_array.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_gdal_array', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 296, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_gdal_array'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/.../venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/osgeo/gdal_array.py", line 28, in <module>
    _gdal_array = swig_import_helper()
  File "/.../venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/osgeo/gdal_array.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _gdal_array
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_gdal_array'
>>>
```

(Exact output on terminal shown [here](https://pasteboard.co/K18Brt7.png))

My question is what might be the problem and how could I fix it?

[Other answers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/274328/173019) suggest to install numpy first, which I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that when I installed gdal I used a cached version of wheel which was probably  problematic.

Rebuilding gdal fixed the issue.